# Changing indices of qubits in QISKit

Tags: programming, qiskit

I was wondering if something like this is possible in QISKit: let's say we have two registers containing target and ancilla qubits:

$a_0$ -------------------

$a_1$--------------------

$\vdots$

$a_4$ ------------------

$t_0$ ------------------

$t_1$ ------------------

$\vdots$

$t_4$ ------------------

These two registers are stored in one quantum register `qr`. So to access $a_0$ we would type `qr[0]`, to access $a_1$ - `qr[1]`, ..., for $t_5$ - `qr[9]`. We can pass this quantum register as an argument to some function:

```
foo(qr, ...)
```

What I want to do is to interleave the ancilla and target qubits:

$a_0$ -------------------

$t_0$--------------------

$\vdots$

$a_i$ ------------------

$t_i$ ------------------

$\vdots$

$a_4$ ------------------

$t_4$ ------------------

so to access $a_0$ I would type `qr[0]`, for $t_1$ - `qr[1]` and so on. Finally, I would like to pass such `changed` quantum register `qr'` again as an argument to some function

```
foo(qr', ...)
```

and in this function I would like to use these changed indices. Is this possible? Other solution I figured out was to pass array of indices for ancilla and target qubits, but I would like to avoid that. Another option would be to use `swap` gates on these qubits

Comment: I think an array of indices is your best bet, but I'll cross post to the QISKit Slack for  a second opinion.

Comment: So you want to change the order of the qubits? You could use SWAP gates in order to perform the interleaving of the qubits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relationship between your indices can be captured by a map:

$$\{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 1, 6: 3, 7: 5, 8: 7, 9: 9\}$$

You can then use this to specify where operations get applied to in a register.

Here is a simple code in QISKit (generalizes to arbitrary register length):

```
from qiskit import * 
from qiskit.tools.visualization import *

# build a register with k targets and k ancillas 
k = 5
qr = QuantumRegister(2*k)
circ = QuantumCircuit(qr)

# apply cx between ancillas and targets
for i in range(k):
    circ.cx(qr[i], qr[i+k])

circuit_drawer(circ)
```

[image: original]

```
# specify the desired interleaving
# {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 1, 6: 3, 7: 5, 8: 7, 9: 9}
new_qubit_map = {i: 2*i if i < k else 2*(i-k)+1 for i in range(len(qr))}

# create the same circuit, but with the new interleaving
circ_2 = QuantumCircuit(qr)
for i in range(k):
    circ_2.cx(qr[new_qubit_map[i]], qr[new_qubit_map[i+k]])

circuit_drawer(circ_2)
```

[image: interleaved]

Answer (score 3):

A lot of updates have been made to Qiskit. Here's possibly the best way to achieve the desired result:

```
qct = transpile(qc, initial_layout=sum(zip(a,t),()))
```

Here, `a` and `t` are `QuantumRegister` objects.

**Explanation**

Firstly, use separate quantum registers `a` and `t` instead of the default single `qr` register.

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister
n = 5
a = QuantumRegister(n, 'a')
t = QuantumRegister(n, 't')
c = ClassicalRegister(n, 'c')
qc = QuantumCircuit(a,t,c)
qc.cx(a,t)
qc.draw()
```

Here's the output you would get:

[image: a register is at top and t is at bottom]

Now, we can remap/[transpile](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html#qiskit.compiler.transpile) it onto another circuit where the mapping is different. I used `sum(zip(a,t), ())` to create the mapping. `zip` first creates a list of tupples like `[..., (a[i],t[i]), ...]` and then is flattened by `sum()`. The second argument `()`, an empty tuple, is the starting value for the `sum`.

All in all, here's the code to create the remapped/[transpile](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html#qiskit.compiler.transpile)d circuit:

```
qct = transpile(qc, initial_layout=sum(zip(a,t),()))
qct.draw()
```

Here's the output:

[image: a[i] qubit is preceeded by t[i]]

If you are having issues where qc gets decomposed into multiple gates (e.g. `ccx`), then using `basis_gates={d.operation.name for d in qc.data}` should fix it. It is using all the gates present in `qc` as basis gates.

```
qct = transpile(qc, basis_gates={d.operation.name for d in qc.data}, initial_layout=sum(zip(a,t),()))
```